# Tailwind backdrop not applying to dialog element

Tags: reactjs, dialog, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add a backdrop behind a `<dialog>` in a React component in a NextJS app. I'm using Tailwind v3.3.2 and all my other styles are applying correctly, but the styles for `backdrop:bg-gray-500` aren't applying any styles in the browser.

I've written a React component that renders the following:

```
      <dialog className="backdrop:bg-gray-50" open={true}>
        This is a dialog
      </dialog>
```

I would expect this to add a gray backdrop behind the element, but nothing is being applied to the element.

I've looked through the Tailwind docs and this looks like what I've tried: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#dialog-backdrops

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no native backdrop element displayed when using the `open` attribute, as per [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog#open):

> If a `<dialog>` is opened using the `open` attribute, it will be non-modal.

So to show the backdrop, we'd need to use the `.showModal()` method on the `HTMLDialogElement` JavaScript representation of the element, as per [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog#usage_notes):

> The `::backdrop` CSS pseudo-element can be used to style the backdrop that is displayed behind a `<dialog>` element when the dialog is displayed with [`HTMLDialogElement.showModal()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal).

```js
function App() {
  const dialog = React.useRef();
  
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    dialog.current.showModal();
  }, [dialog]);
  
  return (
    <dialog className="backdrop:bg-gray-50" ref={dialog}>
      This is a dialog
    </dialog>
  );
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

Content
```